# Network error with POST request from axios

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, postman

I am using axios to make GET and POST requests to authenticate a user. Everything works fine when I am using Postman, as seen by the screenshot below

[image]

Since I am able to make a POST request successfully by inputting a username, email, and password, I want to use axios in my React Native app so that this HTTP request takes care of registering a new user. However, I run into a 'Network error' when I try to register a new user.

Here is my React code where I want to communicate with my API to register a user

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styles from "./styles";
import axios from "axios";
import { NativeBaseProvider, VStack, Input, Button, Text } from "native-base";
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import { COLORS } from "../../util/colors";

//problem may be here...?
const registerUser = async (username, email, password) => {
  axios
      .post(
        `http://localhost:5050/register`, {
          username: username,
          email: email,
          password: password,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
        }
        )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) =>
      console.log(error));
    };

function RegisterScreen(props) {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <VStack w="100%" space={5} alignItems="center" style={styles.container}>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="jellyfish" size={60} color="black" />
        <Input
          value={username}
          onChangeText={setUsername}
          placeholder="Username"
          borderRadius="10"
          py="2"
          px="3"
          fontSize="14"
          w="80%"
          mb="-2"
        />
        <Input
          value={name}
          onChangeText={setName}
          placeholder="Name"
          borderRadius="10"
          py="2"
          px="3"
          fontSize="14"
          w="80%"
          mb="-2"
        />
        <Input
          value={email}
          onChangeText={setEmail}
          placeholder="Email"
          borderRadius="10"
          py="2"
          px="3"
          fontSize="14"
          w="80%"
          mb="-2"
        />
        <Input
          type={"password"}
          value={password}
          onChangeText={setPassword}
          placeholder="Password"
          borderRadius="10"
          py="2"
          px="3"
          fontSize="14"
          w="80%"
          mb="-2"
        />
        <Button
          onPress={() =>  registerUser(username, email, password)
            //here i am registering a use, wan to call function that calls API
            //console.log("Registering: ", username, name, email, password)
          }
          w="40%"
          py="4"
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text fontSize="lg" bold color={"white"}>
            Register
          </Text>
        </Button>
      </VStack>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  );
}

export default RegisterScreen;
```

For reference, here is how my router is defined for the register POST request

```js
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;
    const data = await users.create({
      username,
      email,
      password,
      role: "CLIENT",
    });
    res.status(201).json({ data });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(err.status || 500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```

When I run my following code and a user inputs a username, email, and password into the text-boxes of my React native app, I get the following error:

```html
Network Error
at node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:14 in createError
at node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:117:24 in handleError
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:609:10 in setReadyState
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:396:6 in __didCompleteResponse
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/_EventEmitter.js:135:10 in EventEmitter#emit
```

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: can you try changing from localhost to your IP ``` http://192.168.43.49:5050/register```?

Comment: @Mohammad I changed to my IP and I am still getting the same error